# How handle 401, 404 or 503 Error PHP API with Angular

Tags: php, angular

i made php api apache with xampp. I want to connect it to an angular application. everything is normal it works for me when I use `http_response_code (200);` but the problem is when I want to return `http_response_code(404);` `http_response_code(500);` or  `http_response_code(401);` . angular says at Access to XMLHttpRequest  'http: //localhost/api/login.php' origin from 'http: // localhost: 4200' Has not blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight reques.

here is my php code

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
//
$username = 'admin1';
if ($username == 'admin'){
    //this is working if username == admin status sent as 200.
    http_response_code(200);
    echo json_encode(array("user" => $username));
    exit();
} else {
    //this is not working if username != admin status sent as 0.
    http_response_code(401);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Invalid username"));
    exit();
}
?>
```

Angular app does not recognize status 401, it only recognizes 200. Please help.

Comment: For options request, send a `200` first with the headers

Comment: Ideally 404 should be from the frontend perspective, why a 404 from the backend to Angular?